# How to analyze firebase database data storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase realtime database has grown over the free limit (1 GB stored) and although I'm happy my project is growing I would like to better analyse it and firebase dashboad doesn't offer better tools for doing it.

I have a few questions:

1. Is there any way I get to know what "nodes" are the biggest in the storage hierarchy?
2. Also the download report only shows the total data downloaded, is there any way I get to know what are the most downloaded nodes?

I'm pretty sure I can optimize some stuff in this database I just need some set of tools to analyse it and show me more detailed info than the dashboard has

Answer (score 1):

There's no built in way to see the JSON size of various nodes. The easiest I've found is to enable backups, get the backup from the Cloud Storage bucket, and then analyze locally on that downloaded backup.

Firebase doesn't keep historical data on what nodes are being accessed (most), but you can use the [database profiler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile) to get a live report on what data is being accessed.

Comment: I that is the problem there isnt any tools out there to deal with big json files (as it was meant to be a data representation and not a whole database snapshot). so all tools i tried they simple crash or cant find enough memory (even my pc having 32GB). Anyway maybe this is just a open market for someone,.